# Which jar file is used during compilation?

Tags: java, jar, compilation

Let's assume I have two jar files on classpath when building my project - myJarFile.jar and myJarFileOld.jar. They contain the same packages and the same classes, but the myJarFileOld.jar contains old implementation, which causes that the compilation fails. I'm not asking for solution of this error, I know that I should remove myJarFileOld.jar to make compilation work. However I'd like to know, what mechanism decides which class from which jar file is used during compilation, when both jar files are present?

Answer (score 0):

When a class needs to be loaded, all jar files in the classpath, in order, are scanned. As soon as the class is found, it's loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Not fully sure, but I believe the order of classpath appearance is deciding. If it's found in first jar, then it's not search in another. However I'm pretty sure that class loader will load both jars at the beginning, and you will get some errors about duplicate code. However I'm not sure this, this is probably related to runtime environment.

Answer (score 0):

you have this feature in Eclipse where you can specify the ordering of the jars that you want to be executed from the project classpath.Go to

```
 Project->Select Properties->Select Build Path from left pane-> go to Order and Export Tab->Select Top or Bottom button-> click ok.
```

The next time you build your project the jar from the classpath will be picked in the order that you have specified.

Comment: Nice feature, thank you, but not usable for me. We use ANT for compilation and the classpath is composed from more sources and one of the sources is the whole lib directory, contained in the project. I was just wondered about the details of the compilation and I hoped I'd get some information here.